# how to make the focus on the different text boxes in angular 2

Tags: angular, focus, viewchild

I have more than 25 text boxes and I need to make the focus on each text boxes based on the user input.

But I don't want to make 25 different reference variables in my HTML also it will affect my angular code being more length.

I am using template

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textVal" #textValue>
```

and my class I used

@ViewChild('textValue') textValue;

this.textValue.nativeElement.focus();

So my question is can I need to create 25 reference variables and 25 view child variables

can anybody give some suggestions??

Comment: Are your 25 inputs static or generated with ngFor?

Comment: My fields are static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `@ViewChildren` in your component:

```
@ViewChildren('input[type=text]')
allInputs;
```

That way you can set the focus on any of those inputs based on your business logic. No need to use reference variables anymore.

Comment: How can I make focus in a specific field with allInputs variable

Comment: allInputs is a QueryList object, which can be iterated upon: https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList